# What does rails new --dev do? What about rails new --edge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I heard about this recently but I'm not sure what it means. It's supposed to "Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout" but what does that mean exactly? What Rails checkout? I can't seem to find anything else out there explaining this further.

Also, how to you use rails new --edge? Can you just give it the url to a git repository and use that to bootstrap your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rails checkout means a folder on your computer where you have cloned the rails git repository. This would be useful if you wanted to work on changes to rails itself.

edge will use the master branch of the rails GitHub repository.

Comment: Excellent that makes sense. I found out about it on a podcast talking about contributing to rails, so this explains what they were talking about. Thanks!

Comment: `--edge` will select the latest stable branch from the [rails github repository](https://github.com/rails/rails), the minimum required ruby version of which matches the used version of ruby. For example, with ruby `2.4.8` it will choose `5-2-stable`. For ruby `2.5.0` it will install `6-0-stable`

Answer (score 9):

`--dev` uses your locally checked-out Rails repository to create the app. `--edge` will use the latest stable version from the Github repository, instead of from your locally installed Rails gem.